# Can wordpress classified websites can Show/Hide different UI elemants based on the addvertisment type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im not sure is this a correct place to ask a question on classified websites on WordPress.

Im planing to make a classified website using WordPress with the help of some purchased theme.

So lets say for a Vehicle based advertisement there will be a Manufacturer year, Millage, Transmission type ... etc. And for a mobile phone based advertisement there will not be things like above.

So in the create new advertisement page how do you handle this, I mean based on the product you need to show / hide different elements from the  new advertisement page UI.

Is it possible or is there any in build mechanism with themes or how to handle above situation?

Comment: It's possible if you write the code for it. I doubt any theme you buy from the Internet will do exactly this out of the box though so -again- you'll have to code this functionality into it.

Comment: ooh. Thanks for the quick response @cabrerahector